# fire callback when tooltip closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using twiiter-bootstrap's [tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) and I want to fire an ajax request, or lets say an alert box when the tooltip closes. The jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#explore').tooltip({
                content : "hi there",
                placement : 'bottom',
    });
});
```

I have also tried other plugins like jquery's [tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default) and craigworks's [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) but I cant figure out a way to fire a callback when a tooltip is closed.

Even if tooltip cant support this, can I use something else like bootstrap's popover or some other workaround?

**What I am trying to achieve is this:**
I have a div with a button in it. If a user clicks that button, a small dialog appears next to the button that asks for some other information. The user can
(1)either ignore it and click anywhere else on the screen to close the dialog
(2) close the dialog by clicking on the 'close' button
(3) submit the answer to the question to close the dialog

In all the 3 cases, I want the div to be replaced by a another ajax-fetched content.
If tooltip had a callback, that would have been nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using Craig's [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) using the `events` property of the plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overlay-seen-it').qtip({
        overwrite: false,
        content: {
        text: "Hi there"
        },
        show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true
        },
        hide:{
        event: 'unfocus'
        },
        events:{
            hide: function(event, api){
            var movie=api.elements.target.closest('.movie');
                movie.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $.get('reco_product_stream.jsp?type=replace', function(data) {
                        var $a = $(data).find('a'); 
                        movie.children('a').replaceWith($a);
                        movie.fadeIn(500);
                    });             
                });                     
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any function listed in `events:hide` property fires when the qtip closes. Resolved by Craig [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-firing-event-from-qtip).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this via `.tooltip`, but you can choose what triggers the tooltip displaying so you can bind your own event to the opposite of that.  The default (what you are using) is `'hover'`:

```
$("#explore").tooltip().on('mouseout', function () { alert('left tooltip'); });
```

Comment: What if I am triggering the tooltip with a click instead of a hover? Also, is there any other way instead of a tooltip with which I can achieve the result ?